# Beginner SQL query with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm kind of a beginner with SQL.

Right now i'm trying to create a bit complex select but i'm getting some error, which I know it's a beginner mistake.

Any help appreciated.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score) AS rank, userID, facebookID, name, score FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Friends  AS FR WHERE userID = ? 
    JOIN 
    Users WHERE Users.facebookID = FR.facebookFriendID
) 
UNION (
    SELECT * FROM User WHERE userID = ?
)
```

Where the 2 ? will be replaced with my user's ID.

The table User contains every user in my db, while the Friends table contains all facebookFriends for a user.

```
USER TABLE
userID | facebookID | name | score

FRIENDS TABLE 
userID | facebookFriendID
```

Sample data

USER

```
A | facebookID1 | Alex | 100
B | facebookID2 | Mike | 200
```

FRIENDS

```
A | facebookID2 
A | facebookID3
B | facebookID1
```

I'd like this result since Alex and mike are friends:

```
rank | userID | facebookID  | name
1    | B      | facebookID2 | Mike
2    | A      | facebookID1 | Alex
```

I hope this was quite clear explanation.

I'm getting this error at the moment:

> Error occurred executing query: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: What DB are you using (and add the keyword)? MS-SQL Server? Since OVER is not supported by all DB's.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a SQL Server. This is part of a query inside my server side azure scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several issues with your query.  `JOINS` come before `WHERE` clauses.  And when using a `JOIN`, you need to specify your `ON` clauses.  Also when using a UNION, you need to make sure the same number of fields are returned in both queries.

Give this a try:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score) AS rank, userID, facebookID, name, score 
FROM ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserId = 'A'
    UNION 
    SELECT U.userId, u.facebookId, u.name, u.score 
    FROM Friends FR 
        JOIN Users U ON U.facebookID = FR.facebookFriendID 
    WHERE FR.userID = 'A' ) t
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/092f8/1)

Also, by the way your using `ROW_NUMBER`, it really will be a Row Number vs a `RANK`.  If you want Rankings (with potential ties), replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`.

Comment: @Axyaxy -- np, glad I could help!